# Recursion in Mysql with as

Tags: mysql

There is a trip table with flights containing columns with the beginning and end of the route. It is necessary to organize a search for a route with several transfers. I can't figure out what my mistake is (error at line 21)?

```
   with RoutesCTE as
(
    select concat(airport_from + '->' + airport_to) as Route
          ,0 as TransfersCount
          ,airport_from
          ,airport_to
    from trip

    union all

    select concat(r.Route + '->' + r1.airport_to) as Route
          ,TransfersCount + 1
          ,r.airport_from
          ,r1.airport_to
    from RoutesCTE r
        join trip r1
            on r.airport_to = r1.airport_from
                and r1.airport_to <> r.airport_from
                  and REGEXP_INSTR('%'+r1.airport_to+'%', r.Route) = 0
)

select Route
from RoutesCTE 
where airport_from = 'MVO'
    and airport_to = 'NOV'
    and TransfersCount <= 2;
```

Comment: Any particular reason for not disclosing the fill error message?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?